# emergency mode starts by default on raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, boot, boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os

When i try to start the raspberry pi 3 .. it gets stuck on:

> You are in emergency mode.After logging in, type “journalctl -xb” to view system logs, “systemctl reboot” to reboot, “systemctl default” or “exit” to try again to boot into default mode.
> Type your root password:

The problem is i don't have the root password and i tried so many solutions on the web but nothing solved my issue..what can i do?

Comment: edit your `cmdline.txt` file and add `init=/bin/sh` to the end of the one and only line in that file - that will get you into a shell as root when you next boot ... at least it will if the sdcard isn't completely corrupted

Comment: @Bravo: Why not make that an answer?

Comment: because it's a duplicate and I can't vote to close

Comment: Most of us would just restore from backup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pi boots into emergency mode by default](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59331/pi-boots-into-emergency-mode-by-default)